# ember how to open external link from a button click

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember 2.12, 
Is it possible to call an action on a button click which navigates the user to an external link (like bbc.com for example). I thought the transitionTo will only know the routes declared in router.js

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). this is standard javascript. Or do `window.location = 'http://example.com'`

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this

```
function goToPage()
{
    document.location.href = "you_url"
}
```